# convert array stored in a string to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array value which is coming from database as an string. I need to convert it into an array. When I check my value in console I can see value as

```
"[["COL1","COL2","COL3"],["COL4","space,"COL5"]]"
```

In order to perform my operations I need it to be in below structure

```
[["COL1","COL2","COL3"],["COL4","space,"COL5"]]
```

I have already tried JSON.parse() and parseJSON

Expected Result :

```
[["COL1","COL2","COL3"],["COL4","space,"COL5"]]
```

Actual Result :

```
"[["COL1","COL2","COL3"],["COL4","space,"COL5"]]"
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` ?!

Comment: Hint: `JSON.parse`

Comment: `JSON.parse()` should work fine, how did you use it?

Comment: i used it like 
JSON.parse("[['COL1','COL2','COL3'],['COL4','space,'COL5']]")

Comment: @ManishMayank you have one missing `"` after space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the outer quotes from your string, then pass the value to [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to get the array.

Also, you have to quote each item correctly, `"space` should be `"space"`.

You can sanitize the string with [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) (assuming the quoting of `space` has been fixed in the DB):

```js
const data = '"[["COL1","COL2","COL3"],["COL4","space","COL5"]]"';

const dataSanitized = data.replace(/^"|"$/g,"");

console.log(JSON.parse(dataSanitized));
```

Comment: Euh.. okay.. eval.. okay.. However, I would add a little warn. Edit: nevermind, you did that already. The suggestion that `eval` works as well is interesting, just worth mentioning that between the two methods, the first one is the one you should use :P

Comment: @Syed Mehtab Hassan, I added an explanation about the string syntax issues.

Comment: data is coming from db. I can edit the inner quotes but outer quote is getting generated automatically

Comment: @Manish Mayank, I updated the answer to show how to sanitize the string and get the array

Comment: This is what i am getting in my console window
var layoutArray = data.Layout;
undefined
layoutArray
"[["COL1","COL2","COL3"],["COL4","space,"COL5"]]"
dataSanitized = layoutArray.replace(/^"|"$/g,"");
"[["COL1","COL2","COL3"],["COL4","space,"COL5"]]"
JSON.parse(dataSanitized)
VM7762:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 40
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: @Manish Mayank, you have to fix the quote after `"space` manually, or in your DB

Comment: space is not what we get for spacebar. It is a string over here

Comment: @Manish Mayank, yes but it should be written as `"space"` and not `"space`

Comment: Hi there is some issue with this output
data.Layout
"[["COL1","COL2","COL3"],["COL4","space","COL5"]]"
layoutArray after performing these operations
["COL1", "COL4", "COL3"]
["COL2", "space", "COL5"]

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you do [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
JSON.parse('[["COL1","COL2","COL3"],["COL4","space","COL5"]]')
```

i would not suggest eval as i just read an article about "how eval is evil"
https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/